# Invariance of numerical radius

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, matrix-analysis

Let $X=\begin{pmatrix} r & x\\ \vert y\vert e^{i\theta} & r\end{pmatrix}$ where $r,x>0, y\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$ and $Y=\begin{pmatrix} r & x\\ \vert y\vert & r\end{pmatrix}$. Is $w(X)=w(Y)$  where $w(X):=\sup\limits_{\Vert\alpha\Vert=1}\vert\langle X\alpha,\alpha\rangle\vert$ is called numerical radius of $X$?

---

Comments: I observed that it is true whenever $r=0$. Do you think $X$ and $Y$ are unitarily equivalent which will give the affirmative conclusion of the question?

Comment: Unitarily equivalent matrices have the same determinant, while $X$ and $Y$ don't (unless $y=0$).

Comment: @MaoWao Yes, correct.